# Should I capitalize a contraction at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: abbreviations

In the following sentence:

> 'cause I know what you been doing on your weekends, girl.

Should the "c" in *cause* be capitalized or does the fact that the first two letters have been replaced by an apostrophe mean that it stays lower case?

Comment: I wouldn't call that an abbreviation. It is a contraction, right?

Answer (score 13):

You should definitely capitalize the first letter. In fact, apostrophe isn't really a letter - it's a character. The first letter in the sentence you presented is "C". The fact that the first two letters have been replaced by an apostrophe simply means the first character is "C".

A very famous case would be Shakespeare's *tis*:

> 'Tis now the very witching time of night

Comment: Just the other day, I saw (on englishSE) someone starting a sentence thus, "I.e., ...". Needless to say it took me a while to understand what it really was. Of course, this is quite different from the OP's case.

Comment: **Shakespeare should not be quoted as standard or even general use of English.** A lot of expressions he use are  "bending the language".